# How can I save variables on refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, save

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>


<head>
    <title>Zautra Levels</title>
    <h2 style="font-family: Trebuchet MS; color: blue;"">Zautra Levels</h2>
    <p> </p>
</head>


<body>

<p>Clickables:</p>
<button id="swag" onclick="lmao()">Gain XP</button> <button id="gold" onclick="getgold()">Get Gold</button> <button id="buyupgrade" onclick="buyupp()">Level Up!</button>
<p> </p>
<div id="total">XP: 0</div>
<div id="goldt">Gold: 0</div>
<div id="upgradess">Level: 0</div>
<div id="upcostt">Required XP: 25</div>



<script>
    var clicks = 0; // How many clicks you have
    var upgrades = 0; // How many upgrades you have purchased
    var upcost = 25; // How much the upgrades cost
    var gold = 0; // How much gold you have

    function updateclicks() { // Declares the function that updates the "Zautra Clicks" Text.
        var v=document.getElementById("total");
        v.innerHTML = 'XP: ' + clicks;
    }

        function updategold() { // Declares the function that updates the "Zautra Clicks" Text.
        var g=document.getElementById("goldt");
        g.innerHTML = 'Gold: ' + gold;
    }

    function updateupgradecounter() { // Declares the function that updates the "Upgrades:" Text.
        var y=document.getElementById("upgradess");
        y.innerHTML = 'Level: ' + upgrades;
    }

    function updateupcost() { // Declares the function that updates the "Upgrade Cost:" Text.
        var z=document.getElementById("upcostt");
        z.innerHTML = 'Required XP:' + upcost;
    }

    var x=document.getElementById("swag"); function lmao() { // When you click the "Click for MOAR Zautra's" Button you get a +1 Click.
        clicks+=1;
        updateclicks();
    }

        var j=document.getElementById("gold"); function getgold() { // When you click the "Click for MOAR Zautra's" Button you get a +1 Click.
        gold+=1;
        updategold();
    }

    var c=document.getElementById("buyupgrade"); function buyupp() {
        if (clicks >= upcost) {
            clicks-=upcost
            upgrades+=1
            upcost*=2
            updateclicks();
            updateupgradecounter();
            updateupcost();
        }
        else
        {
            var clicksdif = upcost - clicks;
            confirm("You need " + clicksdif + " more XP to level up.");
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code for my game that I am working on.
I'm trying to add a button, and when you press it, it saves all of the variables.
If you're level 5 with 26 XP, and 7 gold, you refresh the page, you still have those stats instead of losing them on refresh.

Please help!

(And yeah, I do realize that the code is really messed up, but that is a small issue. I'll fix that sooner or later.)

Comment: use cookies or if in a modern browser [local storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage) if you are wanting everything stored clientside

Comment: just use the localStorage namespace on your persistent data: loading:  var gold = +localStorage.gold;   saving: localStorage.gold = gold;

Comment: are you posting to a java or asp.net web page or what?

Comment: Can anyone show me an example, or give me a template of how it would look in my code?

I can't figure out how to use localStorage.

It just makes my gold say "NaN"

Comment: if you are getting NaN you are more than likely doing math calculations with a string:  `"Some string" * 3` = NaN

Comment: use my code, and add this line to say,  updategold(): localStorage.gold=gold; make sure you use the "+" prefix or Number(localStorage.gold) to avoid NaN when loading.

Comment: But how come if I substitute gold with clicks in the code, the localStorage doesn't work. In updateclicks() I put localStorage.clicks=clicks; and then put var clicks = +localStorage.clicks;
localStorage.clicks = clicks;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that actually the easiest way, easier than cookies, is to pass the values via the URL. Example:

```
<form action="yourPage.php?gold=$amount&level=$whatlevel&experience=$experience" method="POST">
```

//Your refresh button here

```
</form>
```

and then to retrieve those variables when the page reloads, use:  gold=$_POST['gold']

Another option as well is to use the GET method instead of POST.
Keep in mind that the file extension needs to be php for this code to work.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a cookie in php:

```
setcookie("NameOfTheCookie",$value,$expireTime)
```

and `$value` can be an array of values as well.

Comment: But where would I tell it what variable/s to store, and what their value is?